# VBA Dialogue prevent user from changing extension FileFilter option

Tags: vba, openfiledialog, filefilter

Say I have a directory with multiple file types, and that I have already set the file filter to show only CSV files

```
paths = Application.GetOpenFilename("Comma Separated Values (*.csv),*.csv", _
MultiSelect:=True)
```

The above code does apply the filter correctly.

Now when I put an any filter text in the file name editbox and hit open/enter, the file extension filter no longer works/gets reset to the user's filter.

This means that if I have files called `test.doc` and `test.csv` in the same directory and type in `test*` in the open file dialog editbox, both the Word document and the CSV file will show as selectable.

Is this a bug and is there a way around this? That is, I want the **user-defined filter to be an addition to the predefined filter**.

Comment: Call it a bug or a feature, but it's common throughout anything that uses the Windows file dialog box, not just Office/VBA.  I think the only way you could get around it would be to write your own file picker from scratch...

Comment: I'm afraid I kinda have to treat it like a bug - users can inadvertently select files with the wrong file type and cause errors in code, unless accounted for, which was why there was a filter set in the first place. Thanks, just wanted to know if it was intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're asking. I knew I had this one laying around somewhere.

This is without muti select:

```
fileOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv,Word Files (*.doc),*.doc")
```

This is with Muti select plus title:

```
fileOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv,Word Files (*.doc),*.doc", 1, "Pick Your CSV File", , True)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood me - I'll try to explain it a bit clearer. When using the Windows file dialog box, e.g. opening a file in Notepad, browse to a folder with multiple file types. Now type in "*". All files show up, and the original *.txt filter is now ignored, but it's still shown to be active. I was hoping to find a solution disallowing the filter reset when using the Windows file dialog box in VBA.